# HERE Maps API for JavaScript - gives a 403 error

Tags: here-api, heremaps

Hi i'm new with HERE and i'm having trouble to use the map api for javascript. I followed this tutorial https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.35.3/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html and it doesn't work.

I have the 403 error in the dev tools like below.
[image]

Here is the response in the dev tools in the network page
[Reponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go5MN.png)

This is how I add the js file for HERE

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Here is my code I tried to show the map

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            'apikey': '{my_key}'
        });

        // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
        var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

        // Instantiate (and display) the map
        var map = new H.Map(
            document.getElementById('Map_Content'),
            defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
            {
                zoom: 10,
                center: CenterMap//param created before but its an object with lat;lng
            });
```

The last thing I'm doing that i'm not sure is in the Here platform I added a project and I put the service, but I couldn't find the one in the tutorial (Maps API service(s)) so I added the service HERE Map Attributes instead

Comment: In the Web Developer tools (I use Opera for this), go to the Network tab, reload the page, then look for the 403 line which will be in red and you can click on the Response tab and there should be a message from here telling you more information about the problem. Post it back here and people should be able to have more of an idea what is wrong.

Comment: I cant add an image so here is the message that I have in the response section from the network page error: Forbiden, description: These credentials do not authorize access

Comment: Then it seems the API key you're using is wrong. (Inserted where it says {my_key} above.

Comment: I used this key for the geolocalisation and it works fine. Do i need another key for the map for js or I can use the same?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below example of map at the specified location.

```js
/**
 * Moves the map to display over Berlin
 *
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function moveMapToBerlin(map){
  map.setCenter({lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777});
  map.setZoom(14);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:50, lng:5},
  zoom: 4,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
window.onload = function () {
  moveMapToBerlin(map);
}
```

```css
#map {
    width: 95%;
    height: 450px;
    background: grey;
}

#panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
                  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    
    <title>Map at a specified location</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../template.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../test-credentials.js'></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
  <script>window.ENV_VARIABLE = 'developer.here.com'</script><script src='../iframeheight.js'></script></head>
  <body id="markers-on-the-map">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Map at a specified location</h1>
        <p>Display a map at a specified location and zoom level</p>
    </div>
    <p>This example displays a movable map initially centered on the <b>Brandenburg Gate</b> in the centre of Berlin <i>(52.5159°N, 13.3777°E)</i></p>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <h3>Code</h3>
    <p>
        The <code>map.setCenter()</code> method and <code>map.setZoom() </code>method are able to control the location of the map.<br>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='demo.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To access the HERE map you need to have below script in the html page.

The same is defined in the api spec.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.37.1/dev_guide/index.html

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: To access the HERE map you need to have below script in the html page.
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
 The same is defined in the api spec.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.37.1/dev_guide/index.html

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it

Comment: Ok Nico, I will update.